# Airflow ETL pipeline - using schedule date in functions?

Tags: python, airflow

Is it possible to refer to the default_args start_date in your Python function?

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow', 
    'depends_on_past': False, 
    'start_date': datetime(2016, 11, 21),
    'email': ['mmm.mm@mmm.com'], 
    'email_on_failure': True, 
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 1, 
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
}
```

My python script primarily uses subprocess to issue this statement:

```
query = '"SELECT * FROM {}.dbo.{} WHERE row_date = \'{}\'"'.format(database,                                                             select_database(database)[table_int],
                                                                       query_date)
command = 'BCP {} queryout \"{}\" -t, -c -a 10240 -S "server" -T'.format(query, os.path.join(path, filename))
```

The task I want to run is using BCP to query 'Select * from table where date = {}'. Currently, my python script has all of the logic for the date variable (defaults to yesterday). However, it would be nice to refer to the default_arg instead and have airflow handle the dates.

So, to simplify, I want to use the default_arg start_date and schedule (runs each day) to fill in the variable on my BCP command. Is this the right approach or should I keep the date logic in the python script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the right approach, but what you really need is `execution_date`, not `start_date`. You can get `execution_date` as `'ds'` default variable through the context in PythonOperator using `provide_context=True` parameter. The `provide_context=True` parameter passes a set of default variables used in Jinja Templating through `kwargs` argument. You can read more about Default Variables and Jinja Templating in the relevant sections of the documentation. https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/code.html#default-variables
https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/concepts.html#jinja-templating

Your code should look like the following:

```
def query_db(**kwargs):
    #get execution date in format YYYY-MM-DD
    query_date = kwargs.get('ds') 

    #rest of your logic
```

`t_query_db = PythonOperator(
    task_id='query_db',
    python_callable=query_db,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)`

Comment: Cool, let me play around with this real quick. I was confused at first but then I found the Macros section in the API docs which shows 'ds' and 'yesterday_ds' etc.

Comment: Yes, I should have made it more clear as it is indeed very confusing subject. I have updated the answer, so hopefully it explains it a little bit better.